# PDF Generation Not keeping StyleSheet

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

So I am using the codeigniter pdf library from: https://github.com/chrisnharvey/CodeIgniter-PDF-Generator-Library

And it works wonders except, It doesn't keep the style sheet when the pdf is generated.

I am trying to use bootstrap to make it look nice, But when I run the script and download the pdf it doesn't have the styling anymore. What do I need to do to keep the stylesheet linked?

My Controller:

```
public function AdminPracticeSheetLateReport()
{
    $this->load->view('pdf/practiceLateReport');
    $this->pdf->load_view('pdf/practiceLateReport');
    $this->pdf->render();
    $this->pdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
}
```

I am loading the bootstrap stylesheet like so in my view:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is this even possible with this plugin? If not it's quite the crappy plugin if you ask me.

BTW: This library for codeigniter uses the DomPDF

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code of codeigniter and noticed that it does not itself make a PDF, but uses DOMPDF in turn (which is another PHP library). codeigniter does not properly send the html and css to DOMPDF, so in my suggestion you should remove codeigniter and use DOMPDF instead. This should correct your problem and also speed up the conversion by a few miliseconds.

Comment: The additional library creates pdfs for codeigniter using dompdf What's the difference?

Comment: I suggest you directly use DOMPDF, as it would save you some miliseconds which are lost in processing the not very useful codeigniter files.

Comment: That isn't bringing the stylesheets in though, therefore what the question was...